# How do I get rid of "On Behalf Of" from my sent Gmail messages?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I have a Google Apps account with 1 primary domain and a secondary alias domain (let's say example.co.uk and example.com). When I send emails from the alias domain, the receiving person sees the sender as "alex@example.co.uk On Behalf Of alex@example.com", which is a bit messy. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To do this, you need to set up Gmail to send emails via an "external" mail server. However, since the alias domain is already registered with Google, you can in fact set this "external" server to their servers and have it work just fine!

- Google Workspace Admin -> Apps -> Google Workspace -> Gmail -> End user access -> Enable `Allow per-user outbound gateways` in Domain admin.
- Gmail -> Settings -> Accounts -> Edit Info (on alias account) -> Next Step -> Send through example.com SMTP servers (recommended for professional domains)...
- SMTP Sever: smtp.gmail.com, Port 465
- Username: alex@example.co.uk (Note: not the alias domain login, but your main Gmail login)
- Password: (Password for the above account)
- Select Always use a secure connections (SSL) when sending mail.

If you don't have this other domain added as an alias and are just sending from an additional email address you'll have to send via the email servers of this other domain.

(Yes, I know I answered my own question, but it took me an age to figure this out, so I wanted to share it!)

Comment: Yup, that's how I do it.

Comment: Doesn't work, the parent domain is still visible in the email headers: `Return Path`, `Recieved-SPF` and `Authentication-Results` all have parent domain details in it.

Comment: Do you still get the On Behalf Of message then? If so, is the parent domain registered as an alias with Google Apps?

Comment: Answering your own question is totally fine! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I followed your instructions above and the email was sent succefully. The alias domain is set up in Google Apps, but I still get the "on behalf of" message. Any other tips?

Comment: Sorry, no... it works that way for me, so I've never needed to try another way. Have you got the domain authentication / SPF stuff set up? I do, but no idea if that affects this or not...

Comment: This is very odd. I have two separate Google Apps installations on two domains. I followed this guide on both, one displays the "via" and one doesn't. The headers for both emails are identical, except that the one that shows the "via" passes its SPF. I'll change the SPF headers now and retest, although I don't think it's related.

Comment: It looks like Google have got it wrong. Once I set the SPF field properly for my domain, the "via" field started appearing. I would imagine this would be the other way around.

Comment: So what if you don't have this option?

Comment: If you are usign G Suite you need to turn on this setting in Domain admin first `Allow users to send mail through an external SMTP server when configuring a "from" address hosted outside your email domain`

Comment: This does not work in 2021.

Comment: @Pie - What part of it doesn't work? Mine is still working fine after all these years, but interestingly I don't see the option under Edit Info on the alias to specify an external SMTP server any more. When I saved my settings for my alias it removed the "Mail is sent through smtp.gmail.com" detail but it still appears to work OK and doesn't show On Behalf Of... so it still appears OK to me.

Comment: @x3ja Are you able to post a few screenshots on how exactly you have yours setup?

Answer (score 4):

You can use gmail's send-through feature. Under settings -> accounts and import, edit the email address in question, and when prompted, choose to "send email through example.com SMTP servers". After configuring the SMTP server settings, you should be good to go.

Comment: Because this was an alias domain (configured to have Google as its mail servers), there were no external mail servers. It took me a while to figure out that I could just set the servers to Google's ones... see my answer below :)

Comment: The only thing you can do currently is change the "reply to" address, in regards to a gmail address, in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my writeup on why the accepted answer both works and doesn't:

http://www.stavros.io/posts/how-properly-configure-google-apps-email/

Basically, you need to set both the SPF and DKIM fields for "via" to go away. There's a bug that removes "via" if you have neither set, but that's just a bug, and you really should set both for deliverability anyway. That should allow you to properly remove the "on behalf of" display in Gmail.

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. Even with SPF, DKIM and DomainKeys configured you still get "on behalf of". The only solution that worked for me was setting up Gmail to use itself as an external SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

What Stavros suggested vastly improves the reliable delivery of our emails to any outside domains and will cause it to not go to spam.

However to finally clinch it, I turned ON an important option of "Allow Per User External Gateways" in Gsuite Admin found under "https://admin.google.com/ac/apps/gmail/ enduseraccess"

What this does is under the Email that we add, after Clicking Next Step, instead of just refreshing it as a Saved option, it takes to a next screen of providing the SMTP server login details of the outbound domain and there you can again give the userid@aliasdomain name and password.

This finally ensured that the mails always go out as user@aliasdomain without the receiving outlook clients showing On Behalf of or Via.

I guess the steps Stavros advised are also needed at the DNS level but he may have assumed that this step is already turned on and despite giving SMTP details the On Behalf shows up.

So what is missing in your case could be the enabling of "Allow Per User External Gateways"

Comment: I have "Allow per-user outbound gateways" enabled but have the same issue. When I attempt to add the secondary address, it does not prompt for SMTP credentials unless it is a non-Gmail/Google Workspace account.