# How to setup email forwarding for subdomains? e.g. user@foo.bar.com -> recipient@gmail.com

Tags: gmail, dns, google-domains

I recently purchased a domain from Google domains, and am using email forwarding to forward emails to a specific Gmail address.

As of right now, emails are forwarded from an address under the format of `user@domain.com`.  Is it also possible to forward emails from an address under the format of `user@subdomain.domain.com`?

In DNS, I've created a new MX record `subdomain.domain.com` and set the value to match Google's default MX records. However, I am now stuck on how to forward emails from `user@subdomain.domain.com` to my Gmail account.

Whenever I use the normal email forwarding option given by Google domains and try to forward `user@subdomain.domain.com` to my Gmail address, it says "invalid alias".

**Resources Used:**

- Google Support (MX Records):  [Set up email forwarding with custom name servers](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9428703)
- Google Support: [Forward your emails from email aliases](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241)
  <sup>Didn't work for me.  Only allows forwarding from `user@domain.com`</sup>
- Web Applications Question: [How can I setup Google Apps Email for a subdomain?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1009/)
  <sup>This gave me the idea of mirroring Google's MX records, but [this solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/1010/) and others were for Google Workspace which didn't apply to me.</sup>

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm looking for the same thing.

Comment: U need to configure an domain alias like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mailbox-migration/migrate-google-mail-prerequisite-create-mail-routing-subdomain-google-domain#create-a-subdomain-in-google-admin-console