# How to use Gmail's "Send Mail As" with another Gmail account through SMTP without "On Behalf Of"?

Tags: gmail, privacy, smtp

Related to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/196/how-do-i-get-rid-of-on-behalf-of-from-my-sent-gmail-messages), I want to remove the "On Behalf Of" when I send an email from another Gmail account via the web ui. So, as of now, my email is being shown as `From emailA@gmail.com on behalf of emailB@gmail.com`. When inputting the email into the settings, Gmail appears to detect that the email is another Gmail account and does not ask you whether or not to use another SMTP server. Anyone has any ideas on how I can get around this?

Comment: Does this still happen? I was trying to reproduce this by sending from a@gmail.com as b@gmail.com to c@gmail.com, but I didn't see any message like "From b@gmail.com on behalf of a@gmail.com" in Gmail's interface. If it still does happen, then which app are you using that displays these kind of messages?

Comment: Gmail is immune to it - has to do with how it reads the email headers.  It's most noticeable when sending mail to an Outlook user.

Comment: I wonder how many people have accidentally (and unknowingly) given away email addresses and names to people they didn't mean to because the 'send mail as' feature doesn't protect their identity. I think Gmail should make this much clearer. This is a serious privacy issue.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: That's exactly what happened to me and how I ended up finding this question right now. I'm stunned that so many people I didn't intend to have my personal address now have it because of this...

Answer (score 10):

Alright, I figured one way to do this. In order for this to work you need an email account without an @gmail.com address. I used a Google Apps account, but another service provider's should be fine as well (e.g. @yahoo.com, @hotmail.com, etc.). The key is, that when you press the "Next Step" button in the "Add another email address you own", it must ask you the "Send mail through your SMTP server?" question. If it does not, you must use some other email provider.

Here are the steps:

1. Press the Send mail from another address button.
2. For the email address, enter in a non-gmail address that you own. It doesn't mater which one you choose, no one will see it. The only thing that is important is that you can access it.
3. Press Next Step.
4. Choose to Send through [domain.com] SMTP servers.
5. Enter in the credentials for the other gmail account you want to send as:

   - SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
   - Username: example@gmail.com (the other gmail address you want to send as)
   - Password: (the password to login to the above gmail address)
   - Use SSL
   - Port: 465
6. Press Add Account
7. Verify the address by clicking on the link that was sent to you.
8. Send an email message, and choose to send it as that temporary account from step 2.

Even though you chose to send as the address from step 2, it will appear as the email address you chose from step 5. This is more of a temporary workaround, since this seems like a bug in Gmail, which may be fixed sometime in the future.

Comment: If the sub email account is also set up such that it is checked with pop3, then you aren't able to keep the anonymous level when replying.

Comment: It works for SMTP though, thanks a lot!

Comment: Alright, we deceived google, it works, but Outlook somehow defaults mail send by this method to unwanted emails. This result kinda contradicts the initial purpose since it is only Outlook which shows 'On Behalf Of' and all the trouble was for it.

Comment: I have been using this method for years. However, I just took a look at the header information in Outlook, and now I see the non-gmail address in the header as "X-Google-Original-From: Name <non_gmail@notgmail.com>".

I don't know when this change happened, but it could have been a while now. It still doesn't show up in the normal Outlook UI, so it's still successful at eliminating the "on behalf of" issue. But when I first implemented this in 2012, I remember searching the headers, and did not find the non-gmail address. It shouldn't be a problem, since most people don't look at headers.

Comment: This no longer seems to work; I just set this up and the "From" address is listed as the address I added, not the GMail address I signed in as.

Comment: This still works fine for me, besides the extra info that I noted above.

Comment: Whatever address you enter in the "Send mail from another address button" on the first screen. That is the address that mail gets sent from. NOT the address you enter on the 2nd screen for the SMTP settings.

Answer (score 3):

For users attempting to send email from a Google Apps account address via a different gmail address, while avoiding the "on behalf of" issue. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25238515/251374), I can confirm that Google requires the following security setting change before you are allowed to "Send mail as" a different Gmail/Google Apps account.

**STEPS**

1. Log into the account whose credentials you will be entering into the
   "Send mail as" screen.
2. "Turn on" access for less secure apps by
   going here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
3. Complete the "Send mail as" steps using your full email address and
   password.

For Google Apps accounts with the "access for less secure apps" setting disabled, your gApps account admin will need to change the settings here:

```
https://admin.google.com/[YourDomain.com]/AdminHome#ServiceSettings/edit=org&notab=1&service=securitysetting&subtab=lesssecureappsaccess
```

**COMPLETED**

In your Gmail account settings, the "Send mail as" section will show your other email address with the following:

[image: Send mail as settings]

Google Support Pages on this topic:

- [Allow less secure apps to access accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)
- [Send mail from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370)
- [Google Apps SMTP settings to send mail from a printer, scanner, or app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

Comment: I believe you can't allow "less secure apps" access if 2 factor auth is on. :(

Comment: Note: the thing to do for 2FA is to create an app-specific password.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to find this page, seems Google change the place again... SMTP do not appear, and I can't find the "Allow users to send mail through an external SMTP when

> configuring a "from" address hosted outside your email domains"...
>   Any cue?
>
> > I hassle with this for some time now and had the same problem as you:
>
> Gmail appears to detect that the email is another Gmail account and
>   does not ask you whether or not to use another SMTP server.
>
> But I found this blog posting and found the discussion in the comments
>   very useful. If you have a "Google Apps for Business" account, you
>   need to enable the following option:
>
> go to www.google.com/a/ Settings -> Email -> General In "Outbound
>   relay" check "Allow users to send mail through an external SMTP when
>   configuring a "from" address hosted outside your email domains" It
>   seems to take a while for that option to get activated in all your
>   accounts. After this, you should be able to configure the external
>   SMTP.
>
> Blockquote

Comment: This is confusing.  Is it supposed to be an answer but you can't find the source, or is it a new question?

Comment: Finally we found it, google often change the place things are... We had t disable it and to reactivate it to be effective...

Comment: Please edit your findings into the answer then

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot, but you can try adding the account with its `@googlemail.com` address instead of its `@gmail.com` address.

(Any mail sent to `userA@googlemail.com` will arrive at `userA@gmail.com`'s address.)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not prompt regarding smtp either.

Answer (score 0):

I used to be able to find documentation of this fact, but searches at this time turn up nothing.

Anyway, Google does not support using alternate SMTP settings for sending as another Gmail account. I'm not sure why, though; I just know they don't support it.

Comment: I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: There are no workarounds that I know of.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff did you happen to find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I hassle with this for some time now and had the same problem as you:

> Gmail appears to detect that the email is another Gmail account and does not ask you whether or not to use another SMTP server.

But I found [this blog posting](http://glenn.eu/2010/05/10/google-apps-aliases-nicknames-without-on-behalf-of/) and found the discussion in the comments very useful. If you have a "Google Apps for Business" account, you need to enable the following option:

- go to www.google.com/a/
- Settings -> Email -> General
- In "Outbound relay" check "Allow users to send mail through an external SMTP when configuring a "from" address hosted outside your email domains"

It seems to take a while for that option to get activated in all your accounts. After this, you should be able to configure the external SMTP.

Comment: I was unable to find the option Outbound relay

Comment: @Pedro77 make sure you use the admin console for your Google Apps for Business account. Go to http://www.google.com/a/yourdomain.com (replacing yourdomain.com with your actual registered domain), login and look for the setting as described above. This is different from the settings within the gmail app. If you are on `https://mail.google.com/mail/...` you're in the wrong place!

Comment: Ok, I was on the wrong place. Anyway, I was able to use smtp already, I think it is because the account is different from @gmail.com.

Answer (score -1):

"On behalf of" problem of custom from address is already solved. You need to use the SMTP Server than Gmail server. [Globinch explained this on their site](http://www.globinch.com/2011/01/08/custom-from-address-gmail-send-mail-from-another-address/).

Comment: Please read the question.  *When inputting the email into the settings, GMail appears to detect that the email is another GMail account and does not ask you whether or not to use another smtp server.*

Answer (score -2):

OK, so this is easy, but may cost some cash.

The reason that gmail does this is that for security and to stop its servers being marked as spam it need to state the correct "From" address.

You need to specify an SMTP server that google will use to "send" your mail that will allow relays for the address you have chosen. For companies this is easy, for individuals, not so much.

if, like me, you own your own domain you can use a service like DynDNS to fix this issue. If you purchase a [Mailhop Outbound](http://www.dyndns.com/services/mailhop/outbound.html) account you can add their SMTP service to google for any email address you like.

Once setup in your "Send mail as" list you email will have the words "Mail is sent through: outbound.mailhop.org" under it. You can use the [instructions on the Google site](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=22370) for configuring gmail to use this service.

This will remove that pesky "Sent on behalf of" message that we all hate for only $20 per year. Not bad.

Comment: I think the question was misunderstood.. this wouldn't solve the issue.

Comment: It does indeed solve the exact problem defined in the question. This is how I solved it and it works just fine. The ideal solution is to use a Google Apps account as defined above, but this works regardless.