# Sending email as a G Suite group in Gmail?

Tags: g-suite-administrator

I created a Group in G Suite and added a number of accounts to it. I want people who are members of the group to be able to send emails as that groups email address but it doesn't seem like that's possible.

What I had thought would work was, in Gmail, going to "Settings" -> "Accounts" -> "Send mail as" and then clicking on "Add another email address". The problem with that is that it's asking for SMTP login info. It correctly deduced that aspmx2.googlemail.com is the SMTP Server we'd want to use but as for the username or password...  what would that be?

Comment: What kind of group you do you created? Do your organization have enabled Google Groups for Business?

Comment: @Rubén - I'm not completely sure what you're first question is trying to ask lol but as for your second question...  in https://admin.google.com/ac/billing/subscriptions I have "Android management", "Chrome Upgrade" and "G Suite Business".

Comment: Sorry... the missing word is *group* (added to my previous comment)

Comment: Here is the corresponding official help artilce [Send emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén - it says "_For school or work accounts, enter the SMTP server (for example, smtp.gmail.com or smtp.yourschool.edu) and the username and password on that account_". That's where I'm running into problems, as detailed in my original post. Quoting that post, "_It correctly deduced that aspmx2.googlemail.com is the SMTP Server we'd want to use but as for the username or password... what would that be?_". This is a GROUP email - a mailing list, basically. If there's an SMTP password associated with a GROUP that would be news to me - certainly I haven't set any such password!

Comment: Please read the whole article

Comment: @Rubén - I have. It's a pretty short article. I'm not sure what you're hinting at. And in any event, SE tends to frown upon link only answers. Sure, you posted the link as a comment - not as an answer, but still...

Answer (score 3):

First, yes it's possible to use a group email address as Gmail alias.

NOTE: I have done this only for  G Suite / Google Workspace with Google Groups for Business enabled.

1. The user should be a member of the group
2. The group should be set to allow users to send emails as the group
3. The group should be set to allow anyone to post to the group in order to make it able to receive the verification code sent by Gmail when an different address is being added (see Ref. 1 for details)

If your users are asked to add a SMTP email server username and password, first you should  enable less secure apps, then use:

- smtp.gmail.com
- the user email address
- the user password*

If the user has enabled 2 Step Verification, then they should use an app password, otherwise they might have to enable their account for less secure apps.

References

1. [Send emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)
2. [Check Gmail through other email platforms](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en)
3. [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)
4. [Sign in with App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Related

- [How do I get rid of "On Behalf Of" from my sent Gmail messages?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/196/88163)
- [How to use Gmail's "Send Mail As" with another Gmail account through SMTP without "On Behalf Of"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4469/88163)